# Get data from nested reactable of shiny dashboard with Reactable.getState

Tags: r, shiny, reactable

I have a dashboard created with `shiny` and the `reactable`package. I would like to download the data shown in the table into an Excel file with `Reactable.getState` The problem is that I can only get the data of the inner tables if they were expanded.

The following example shows this problem for the inner table of the first row.

If you click *Get data*, it shows *NULL*.

If you expand the first row and click *Get data*, it shows the data of the inner table.

Is there a way to get the data of the inner table without expanding it?

```
library(shiny)
library(reactable)
library(jsonlite)

data <- as.data.frame(unique(MASS::Cars93[, 1]))  

registerInputHandler(
  "xx",
  function(data, ...){
    fromJSON(toJSON(data))
  },
  force = TRUE
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(
      7,
      tags$button(
        "Get data",
        onclick = '
          var state = Reactable.getState("cars1");
          Shiny.setInputValue("dat:xx", state.sortedData);
        '
      ),
      reactableOutput("cars")
    ),
    column(
      5,
      verbatimTextOutput("data")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$cars <- renderReactable({
    reactable(data, details = function(index){       
      part_data <- MASS::Cars93[MASS::Cars93[, 1] == data[index, 1], 2:5]                       
      htmltools::div(style = "padding: 1rem",
                     reactable(part_data, outlined = TRUE, elementId = paste0('cars', index))
      )},  filterable = TRUE)
  })

  output$data <- renderPrint({
    input$dat
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You can do `Reactable.toggleAllRowsExpanded("cars")` in the JavaScript code to expand the rows.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent: Thanks, this works perfectly. At first I expand the rows and then directly collapse them again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `Reactable.toggleAllRowsExpanded("cars")` in the JavaScript code to expand the rows, then send the table to the Shiny server, then collapse the rows:

```
    onclick = '
      Reactable.toggleAllRowsExpanded("cars");
      var state = Reactable.getState("cars1");
      Shiny.setInputValue("dat:xx", state.sortedData);
      Reactable.toggleAllRowsExpanded("cars");
    '
```